# Improve performance of multiple insert and update queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `Sale_Source` (10.000 rows) and `Sale_Target` (1 billion rows). I have four queries to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` `Sale_Target` with the data from  `Sale_Source`.

- Source table has a nonclustered index on `id` and `Date`
- Target table has indexes on `id` and `Date` but i have disable them to improve the Performance

Queries

INSERT query #1:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sale_Target (id, Salevalue, Salestring, Date)
    SELECT id, Salevalue, Salestring, Date 
    FROM dbo.Sale_Source s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Sale_Target t ON s.id = t.id)
```

UPDATE query #1 (when the date are the same):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Salevalue = s.Salevalue,
    t.Salestring = s.Salestring
FROM dbo.Sale_Source s 
JOIN dbo.Sale_Target t ON t.id = s.id AND s.Date = t.Date
WHERE t.Salevalue <> s.Salevalue OR t.Salestring <> s.Salestring
```

UPDATE query #2 (when date on SaleSource > Date on SaleTarget):

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Salevalue = s.Salevalue,
    t.Salestring = s.Salestring 
FROM dbo.Sale_Source s  
JOIN dbo.Sale_Target t ON t.id = s.id AND s.Date > t.Date
```

UPDATE query #3 (when id on Source is `null` in `join` clause):

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Salevalue = null,
    t.Salestring = null 
FROM dbo.Sale_Source s 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sale_Target t ON t.id = s.id 
WHERE s.id IS NULL
```

The four queries require 1 hr. 30 mins. to finish, which is very slow for the source table with only 10.000 rows. I think the problem here is that each time when four queries run, they need to `JOIN` two source and target tables again, which cost a lot of time.

Therefore I have an idea:

1. I will create a query which saves the matched rows between two tables (source and target) into table *temp_matched*, and save the non matched rows (non matched to target) into *temp_nonmatched*.

   For this, I have problem now with `MERGE` query because in `MERGE` we can't save data into another table.
2. Use *temp_nonmatched* in `INSERT` query, in `UPDATE` query. I will replace table *Sale_Source* with *temp_matched*.

Do you have any idea to do it or can we optimize these four queries in another way?

Thank you.

---

Table Definition:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale_Target](
>    [id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
>    [Salevalue] [numeric](8, 0)  NULL,
>    [Salestring] [varchar](20)  NULL,
>    [Date] [Datetime2](7) NULL
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
> CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX "NCCI_Sale_Target"  
>     ON [dbo].[Sale_Target] (id,Date) 
>
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale_Source](
>    [id] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
>    [Salevalue] [numeric](8, 0)  NULL,
>    [Salestring] [varchar](20)  NULL,
>    [Date] [Datetime2](7) NULL
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
> CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX "NCCI_Sale_Source"  
>     ON [dbo].[Sale_Target] (id,Date)
> ```

Comment: Can you share the table definitions and indexes? Take a look at the execution plans and figure out where the bottleneck is at. You can also upload your execution pplan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Then we can see what is happening.

Comment: Your table with 1 Billion rows is a heap?

Comment: actually, i have disable the Target Table Index to improve the Performance of INSERT and UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

> Target Tables has no Index.

First thing I would do is index the Target Table on `id` and `date`.

Comment: i have tested, when i enable index on Target Table, the 4 Query takes longer time than without index. The Problem with the INDEX in the Queries is that System need to UPDATE the INDEX also which costs time

Comment: I'd have to see the execution plan of that query to comment.   The Index shouldn't affect the speed of the UPDATE since the columns being updated do not participate in the index I proposed.

Comment: i have analysed a solution with partition.: